# Index movie duration

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how I'm intended to store my movies duration field (e.g. 02:20:13 for a movie that is 2 hrs, 20min, and 13 sec long) so that users searching the index can facet on movie duration.

Like in the facet they can select from 01:00:00 to 02:00:00 for movies that are between 1 to 2 hours long. I tried to store duration as a DateTime value and have that indexed but that includes dates which don't seem relevant to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to store duration as a field of type `Edm.Int32` where the field value represents the total duration in seconds. While you could use `Edm.DateTimeOffset` to represent durations, it doesn't really buy you any additional functionality over using a plain integer. It's basically a tradeoff: If you use date/time, your app has to ignore the date part; If you use integers, your app needs UI logic to render them as durations in `hh:mm:ss` format.

Comment: I thought about that and it seems like a workaround, doesn't it? Azure Search have built in logic for creating ranges if I index sets of integers. I want to do it like according to "by design".

Comment: So you want an Edm.Duration data type?

Comment: Feel free to add a proposal on our User Voice page: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search In the meantime, please mark the answer as accepted or let me know how I could clarify it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this is of course the right answer to the question :)